# Pass Numpy array to Compiled Code (Wolfram Engine, Wolfram Client, Python)

Tags: python, free-wolfram-engine, wolfram-client

What List-like structures in Python can Wolfram Client handle and how can support for new structures be added?

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210215/12858) I describe how to execute from Python, code in a Mathematica package that that has been compiled to C.

One such compiled function for test purposes is this:

```
compiledTestFunction2 = 
    Compile[{{n, _Real, 1}, {m, _Real, 1}},
        Module[{},
            Cross[n, m]
        ],
        CompilationTarget->"C", "RuntimeOptions"->"Speed"];
```

(Cross[] is compilable). This function is called from Python by defining

```
compiledTestFunctionPython2 = session.function('compiledTestFunction2')
```

And the function is invoked as

```
compiledTestFunctionPython2(thing1, thing2)
```

Using Wolfram Language functions via Wolfram Client to Wolfram Engine we obtain a reference result:

```
thing1 = array.array('f', [1,2,3])
thing2 = array.array('f',[2,3.3,7])
session.evaluate(wl.Cross(thing1, thing2))
```

> ```
> PackedArray([ 4.1, -1. , -0.7])
> ```

We obtain the correct answer if we define thing1 and thing2 as Python:

- Lists  e.g. [1, 2, 3]
- Arrays e.g. array.array('f', [1, 2, 3])
- Tuples e.g. (1, 2, 3), and even
- Sets   e.g. set([1, 2, 3]) despite the lack of ostensible order to sets

but Numpy arrays are not supported. Attempting to use a Numpy array such as

```
thing1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

causes the compiled function to be returned unevaluated with the error:

> Argument … at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size
>   real numbers.

**Questions** What array types does Wolfram Client handle and could support for other structures such as Numpy arrays be added; if so, how? (The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/basic_usages.html#serialization) says Numpy is supported, but does it work for compiled functions?)

And although PackedArray([...]) is returned by default, is there any choice in the matter?

**Update on passing in 26/11/2019**

By trying to force Numpy arrays to be of a particular data type, using

```
thing1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0., 3.0], dtype = np.float16)
```

we discover, from the Not Supported Error for dtype('float16'), that Wolfram Client serialisation (in \wolframclient\serializers\encoders\numpy.py) supports the following: int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, float32, float64, complex64, complex128

However, no explicit float choices are acceptable to the compiled function.

It looks as though any existing numpy array must be coerced back to some other form, and after a few experiments it seems that the most efficient way is e.g.

```
thing1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype = np.float64)
thing1 = array.array('d', thing1)
```

but the differences between array, list and tuple are small.

**Update on receiving back 26/11/2019**

According to the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/public_api.html#evaluating-expressions)

> By default, packed arrays are deserialized as list. Specify a consumer instance that supports NumPy arrays WXFConsumerNumpy

If one then prepares a session with

```
session = WolframLanguageSession(kernelLoc, consumer=WXFConsumerNumpy())
```

then my compiled function that returns a 1D (table) of reals appears back in Python as class 'wolframclient.utils.packedarray.PackedArray' - not numpy array. Why?

I have yet to find the list of deserializers.